# Shuffling pairs in lists of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, shuffle

Given a list of lists as follows:

```
aList = [["1","Number1", "2", "Number2","3","Number3", "4", "Number4"],["3","Number3", "1", "Number1","2","Number2", "4", "Number4"]]
```

I am trying to shuffle every two elements in a sublist to get something like e.g., this:

```
aListNew = [["3","Number3", "1", "Number1","4","Number4", "2", "Number2"],["2","Number2", "3", "Number3","1","Number1", "4", "Number4"]]
```

So it is important that the two successive strings remain together while being shuffled.

Comment: I assume that the `"Number5"` entry is a typo?

Comment: @MarkDickinson absolutely thanks! now it's correct

Comment: Is there any reason to keep this data structure? If the data is in pairs then it would be much clearer to explicitly structure it in pairs, using tuples for example. This would also simplify the next step.

Comment: Yes, this structure is important. But maybe there is a solution with tuples and with a backwards conversion.

Comment: you could take the the ```int``` and shuffle it, then add ```string``` after the int, so it would remain paired.

Comment: if string and int are not related and need to be paired, try out ```dict {}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways you could do this. You don't give any indication of what you have tried or why it didn't work. Nevertheless as this question hasn't yet been answered or closed here is some code. Please review the posting guidelines so your future posts will generate more answers and be less likely to be closed.

```
import random

aList = [["1","Number1", "2", "Number2","3","Number3", "4", "Number4"],["3","Number3", "1", "Number1","2","Number2", "4", "Number4"]]
alist_alt = []

for sublist in aList:
    l = len(sublist)
    r = list(range(0, l ,2))
    random.shuffle(r)

    sublist_alt=[]
    for i in r:
        sublist_alt.append(sublist[i])
        sublist_alt.append(sublist[i+1])

    alist_alt.append(sublist_alt)

print(alist_alt)
```